# Trying to display URL image in JFrame

Tags: java, url, jframe

Trying to display a URL-image in a JFrame window. If this works correctly, when the program runs, a window should open displaying an image. Trying to experiment with URL's and hard-drive paths.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

 class ImageInFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG&t=6m&q=l";
    URL url = new URL(path);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(label);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
  }
```

Compiles just fine, but fails to run. I've been experimenting with some YahooFinance data simply because it's fun to work with due to it's customization. Hope someone can help. Cheers.

Comment: Well, even though it compiles, it doesn't do anything. Just generates a list of errors.

Comment: *"Just generates a list of errors."* If you mean a stack trace, post it as an edit.  It might be that Yahoo does not want their finance data being used by just any application.  Try an image form [here](http://pscode.org/media/#image) first.

Comment: BTW - The posted code works for me here.

Comment: I figured out my error. Yup, thanks. Guess that it did work after all...I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Works fine for me...

Apart from the fact your not handling the exception (which might be useful for diagnostics) and not really loading the program within the EDT, it seems to work just fine...

[image]

```
public class TestURLImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestURLImage();
    }

    public TestURLImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    String path = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG&t=6m&q=l";
                    System.out.println("Get Image from " + path);
                    URL url = new URL(path);
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
                    System.out.println("Load image into frame...");
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.getContentPane().add(label);
                    f.pack();
                    f.setLocation(200, 200);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {` Heh-heh.  Cool. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Finally made the jump to 7...me likes ;)

Comment: Any chance you can explain to me what your doing with the UIManager? I'm not too familiar with its function.

Comment: The `UIManager` has a number of important roles, the one I'm using it for is to install the system (in my case, Windows) look and feel.  You have a look at [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) for some examples

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look. As an aside, I've had on off issues with running the file: it compiles, but I have "exception in thread main" with a NoClassDefFoundError. Not really sure why it would report this if it compiled.